# Отправить форму, обнулить поля и вывести сообщение

Tags: javascript, ajax, form

Есть форма, но после отправки поля не очищаются, перепробовал кучу вариантов, памагити... )

```js
var ajaxForm = function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#submit").submit(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $("#submit").serialize(),
        success: function(reset) {
          if (reset) {
            $('#form').html('Your form is submited, Thank You !');
            $('#form')[0].reset();
          } else {
            $('#form').html('Your form is not submited');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });

};



ajaxForm();
```

```css
 .form { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px 20px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(315deg,#24b5b0 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,#24b5b0 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" method="POST" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mail.php">
  <label for="names">Наименование организации:
                  <input type="text" name="user_name" id="names" placeholder="Введите наим. организации">
                </label>
  <label for="address">Aдрес организации:
                  <input type="text" name="user_address" id="address" placeholder="Введите адрес">
                </label>
  <label for="email">Email*:
                  <input type="email" name="user_email" id="email" placeholder="Введите email" required>
                </label>
  <label for="phone">Телефон*:
                  <input type="phone" name="user_phone" id="phone" placeholder="Введите телефон" required>
                </label>
  <label for="file">Прикрепить файл:
                  <input class="file" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="upload" id="file">
                </label>
  <label for="massage">Ввести сообщение:
                  <textarea class="massage" name="user_massage" placeholder="Cообщение" id="massage"></textarea>
                </label>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Отправить">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.reset()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp)

```js
var ajaxForm = function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    // ajax goes here
    // success: function goes here
    $('#form').trigger("reset");
    
    $('#some-msg-wrapper').css({
      'display': 'flex',
      'justify-content': 'center',
      'align-items': 'center'
    }).show();
    
    // ajax end
    return false;
  });
  
  $('#some-msg-wrapper #close').click(function () {
    $('#some-msg-wrapper').hide();
  });

};
ajaxForm();
```

```css
.form { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px 20px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(315deg,#24b5b0 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,#24b5b0 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
}
#some-msg-wrapper{
display:none;
position:fixed;
width:50%;
height:50%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#some-msg-wrapper #close{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#some-msg{
  background-color: #fff;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" method="POST" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mail.php">
  <label for="names">Наименование организации:
                  <input type="text" name="user_name" id="names" placeholder="Введите наим. организации">
                </label>
  <label for="address">Aдрес организации:
                  <input type="text" name="user_address" id="address" placeholder="Введите адрес">
                </label>
  <label for="email">Email*:
                  <input type="email" name="user_email" id="email" placeholder="Введите email" required>
                </label>
  <label for="phone">Телефон*:
                  <input type="phone" name="user_phone" id="phone" placeholder="Введите телефон" required>
                </label>
  <label for="file">Прикрепить файл:
                  <input class="file" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="upload" id="file">
                </label>
  <label for="massage">Ввести сообщение:
                  <textarea class="massage" name="user_massage" placeholder="Cообщение" id="massage"></textarea>
                </label>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Отправить">
  
  <div id="some-msg-wrapper">
    <div id="close">X</div>
    <div id="some-msg">
      <p>Some message here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

З.Ы. делать так `$("#submit").submit(function()` в теле `$("#submit").click(function(e)` нет необходимости, т.к. кнопка имеет `type="submit"`

Comment: Спасибо, друг ! )